# ASP.NET MVC5 application throwing NullReferenceException when authorizing

Tags: forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, httpmodule

I have an MVC5 application that is throwing a NullReferenceException on the *production* server when using the `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller. The application is using forms authentication.

The production server is Server 2008 SP 2 (.NET 4.5.1 and IIS 7).

The start of the stack trace is:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +293
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +155
```

I can fix it by setting

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

However, I prefer not to use such a [sledgehammer method](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html).

Is there a cleaner way of fixing this problem?

Comment: Do you have <authentication mode="Forms"> in your web.config? Also check that there is no web.config transformation that changes the authentication mode in release mode.

Answer (score 7):

IIS and IIS Express have some differing behaviors for request authentication. The `HttpContext.User.Identity` property may not be set when the `AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` method executes (hence the `NullReferenceException`), due the fact that the authentication module does not always run.

You could change the precondition for only the authentication modules you need instead of loading all modules for all requests. For example, the FormsAuthenticationModule has: `preCondition="managedHandler"` by default.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
    <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
    <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```