# NullReferenceException only cleared up by using "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nullreferenceexception

I have created an MVC5 application that works fine on my local machine, but throws a `NullReferenceException` when using the `AuthorizeAttribute` on our test server (Server 2008 and IIS 7). I can clear it up with 
`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in the web.config file, but I know this is not a clean fix.

If have already found the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170269/asp-net-mvc5-application-throwing-nullreferenceexception-when-authorizing) but no answers have been put forth yet, and I can find no suggestions anywhere else that do not involve this approach.  Surely there must be a better way than `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to solve the null reference problem (although this does, indeed, clear up the error)?

Comment: How about a stack trace for the error message? That will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS and IIS Express have some differing behaviors for request authentication. The `HttpContext.User.Identity` property may not be set when the `AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore()` method executes (hence the `NullReferenceException`), due the fact that the form authentication module does not always run.

You could change the precondition for only the FormsAuthenticationModule instead of loading all modules for all requests. By default, the FormsAuthenticationModule has: `preCondition="managedHandler"`.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I also had to do the same for "DefaultAuthentication", but combined that did the trick!